# ng-options (key, values) in object

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

## I want to know how to use ng-options render a select Element works.

```
    var data = {
 china:[
{name:'shanghai',code:1},
{name:'zhejiang',code:2}
],
 us:[
{name:'Alabama',code:3},
{name:'Alaska',code:4}
]
};


than,will render like this

<select>
 <optgroup label="china">
     <option value="1">shanghai</option>
     <option value="2">zhejiang</option>
</optgroup>
 <optgroup label="us">
     <option value="3">Alabama</option>
     <option value="4">Alaska</option>
</optgroup>
</select>
```

### use ng-options how to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is working code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<select>
 <optgroup label="{{key}}" ng-repeat="(key,value) in data">
     <option value="{{val.code}}" ng-repeat="val in value" ng-selected="{{val.code==defaultValue}}">{{val.name}}</option>
</optgroup>
</select>

</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
     $scope.defaultValue = "4"; // Any default value you want here
     $scope.data = {
 china:[
{name:'shanghai',code:1},
{name:'zhejiang',code:2}
],
 us:[
{name:'Alabama',code:3},
{name:'Alaska',code:4}
]
};
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks, ng-repeat it is OK,I want to know how to use ng-options. bcz use ng-repeat can not bind default value

Comment: @wangzhen , you can use ng-selected in ng-repeat like this.
<option value="{{val.code}}" ng-repeat="val in value" ng-selected="{{val.code==defaultValue}}">{{val.name}}</option> by this you can bind default value to your model

Comment: @ChiruAdi what is defaultValue here.

Comment: $scope. defaultValue ="3"; // whatever want to bind from your repeating  options

Comment: Yes got it . I will update my answer.

Comment: @wangzhen i have updated my answer. Let's have a look.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to change your object structure something like

```
const data = [
  {name: 'shanghai', code: 1, group: 'china'},
  {name: 'zhejiang', code: 2, group: 'china'},
  {name: 'Alabama', code: 1, group: 'us'},
  {name: 'Alaska', code: 2, group: 'us'}
]
```

And use in HTML to bind this object to select with ng-options

```
<select ng-model="sel" ng-options="t.code as t.name group by t.group for t in data">
```

Comment: thanks, but normally we can not change the object structure from Server  API. also,that is a solution :)

Comment: You can change this on fly as well no need to rely on server side opject