# ng-options doesn't highlight selected value on initial load

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

Consider a next code sample:

http://plnkr.co/edit/LA6fu1vdzRWFaQw6Zl6S?p=preview

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="main">
  <select novalidate="" ng-model="selectedItem" ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in items track by item.id"> </select>
</body>

</html>


var app = angular.module('app', [])

.controller('main', ['$scope',function($scope) {
  $scope.items = [
    {"id":0,"name":"a"},
    {"id":1,"name":"b"},
    {"id":2,"name":"c"},
    {"id":3,"name":"d"}
  ];
  $scope.selectedItem = 1;
}])
```

I expect that on initial load select element will have a "b" option selected, but it doesn't. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: @AlekseySolovey , still doesn't work:
http://plnkr.co/edit/LA6fu1vdzRWFaQw6Zl6S?p=preview

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50483263/ng-options-key-values-in-object/50483679 
check this answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to:

- use an updated version of AngularJS (Change `1.1.5` to `1.6.10` in your script)
- remove `track by item.id`, it's used for `ng-repeat`, not `ng-options`

Here is a working demo:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', [])

.controller('main', ['$scope',function($scope) {
  $scope.items = [
    {"id":0,"name":"a"},
    {"id":1,"name":"b"},
    {"id":2,"name":"c"},
    {"id":3,"name":"d"}
  ];
  $scope.selectedItem = 1;
}])
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.10/angular.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="main">
    <select novalidate=""
      ng-model="selectedItem" 
      ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in items">
    </select>
    {{selectedItem}}
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Sajeetharan here is what I call a "normal" approach!

Comment: @Maris yeah right! i have answered the same so many times, did not come in mind though!